# Restrict User From creating More than 50 Records per week

Tags: trigger

1. I need to check both the existing records that are already created in this week and also newly creating records in the same week.
2. I should limit more than 100 records creation by user
3. I want to know which user created the records
   Here is my code.

```java
public class RestrictAccountByUser {
    public static void limitNoOfAccounts(List<Account> AccountList) {
        Integer maxAccounts = 50;

        List<Account> thisweekAccountList = [select id, CreatedById, CreatedDate from Account where CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK AND CreatedById = :UserInfo.GetUserId()];

        if (thisweekAccountList.Size() > maxAccounts)
            AccountList[0].addError('Dear user you have exceeded the maximum number of Accounts allowed to create this week.');
    }
```

Comment: in an opportunity object

Comment: welcome to SFSE, can you please let the committee know that what exactly you have tried and what problems you are facing in that?

Comment: Here is my code,

Comment: Hi Samanya. Please update your question with any additional info you can provide.

Comment: public class RestrictAccountByUser {

    public static void limitNoOfAccounts(List<Account> AccountList) {

        Integer maxAccounts = 50;

        List<Account> thisweekAccountList = [select id,CreatedById,CreatedDate from Account  where CreatedDate=THIS_WEEK AND CreatedById=:UserInfo.GetUserId()];

   if (thisweekAccountList.Size()>maxAccounts)         

            AccountList[0].addError('Dear user you have exceeded the maximum number of Accounts allowed to create this week.');

    }  

 this is my trigger handler class

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code and modify the condition and SOQL filter as per your choice.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Account WHERE CreatedById =: UserInfo.getUSerId() AND CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK];
System.debug('Average amount' + groupedResults[0].get('expr0'));
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: `COUNT` is not an average.